I want to show the Notification on other app's when using different app's and i am using the display over the other app's Permission
I am trying to implement this feature for my app and when the new notification comes and that notification should display on other app's. but i am getting the notification in background, quite and foreground state. but i want to display them on other app's in background state and quite state. and i am using this third party library(react-native-floating-bubble) and i am getting the permission for display over the other app's but i am unable display when notification comes .
for getting the permission i have used this code
you can read about this library  react-native-floating bubble
import {crequestPermission} from 'react-native-floating-bubble';

  requestPermission()
    .then(() => console.log('Permission Granted'))
    .catch(() => console.log('Permission is not granted'));

and this code for when the new notification comes that time i want to display over the other app's
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import notifee, {AndroidImportance} from '@notifee/react-native';
import {Alert, DeviceEventEmitter} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {showFloatingBubble} from 'react-native-floating-bubble';
import Sound from 'react-native-sound'; // Import Sound for playing audio

export async function requestUserPermission() {
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

  if (enabled) {
    console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
  }
}

// Function to handle showing floating bubble and playing sound
const handleNewNotification = async () => {
  try {
    // Show floating bubble
    showFloatingBubble(10, 10).then(() => console.log('Floating Bubble Added'));

    // Play notification sound (adjust the sound file path accordingly)
    const sound = new Sound('notification.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, error => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Error loading sound:', error);
        return;
      }
      // Play the sound when it's loaded
      sound.play(success => {
        if (success) {
          console.log('Sound played successfully');
        } else {
          console.log('Sound playback failed');
        }
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error handling new notification:', error);
  }
};

export const notificationListener = () => {
  messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(async remoteMessage => {
    handleNewNotification();
    console.log(
      'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
      remoteMessage.notification,
    );
    DeviceEventEmitter.emit('notificationListener', remoteMessage);
    console.log('Basya, Laxman');

    // Show floating bubble and play sound on notification open
  });

  // Check whether an initial notification is available
  messaging()
    .getInitialNotification()
    .then(async remoteMessage => {
      if (remoteMessage) {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(
          'notificationListener',
          JSON.stringify(remoteMessage),
        );
        console.log(
          'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
          remoteMessage,
        );

        // Show floating bubble and play sound on initial notification
        handleNewNotification();
      }
    });
};

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background:', remoteMessage);

  // Handle the new notification
  handleNewNotification(remoteMessage.data);
});

export const getToken = async () => {
  await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();
  const token = await messaging().getToken();
  console.log('================Token==========');
  console.log(token);
  console.log('================Token==========');
};

export async function onDisplayNotification() {
  try {
    await notifee.requestPermission();

    const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
      id: 'notification_sound',
      name: 'service_app',
      sound: {uri: 'notification'},
      importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
    });

    const acceptAction = {title: 'Accept', pressAction: {id: 'accept_action'}};
    const rejectAction = {title: 'Reject', pressAction: {id: 'reject_action'}};

    await notifee.displayNotification({
      title: 'Yellowsense',
      body: 'You Got New Customer',
      android: {
        channelId,
        pressAction: {id: 'default'},
        actions: [acceptAction, rejectAction],
        smallIcon: 'ic_logo',
      },
    });

    notifee.onForegroundEvent(async ({type, detail}) => {
      if (type === 'press') {
        const {pressAction} = detail;
        if (pressAction) {
          switch (pressAction.id) {
            case 'accept_action':
              console.log('Accept action pressed');
              break;
            case 'reject_action':
              console.log('Reject action pressed');
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error displaying notification:', error);
  }
}

so please anyone who know how to do this can you please help to solve this problem
